# Not able to see the cookie on chrome also in my frontend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, cookies

Hey I am trying to create an advance auth system where user puts his details while registering and then a otp will sent to users email. So i am using a cookie-parser package to save the generated jwt token but the problem is while I am testing using postman i can see the cookie has been saved but when i trying to do through my react forntend I can't see the cookie in my appication console so when I put the otp which is sent to user to email I got an error you are not logged in which is the error message I set if there is no token. Can any one tell me what is problem. Please any one show me how can do this it almost 2 days now i am stuck here.

One more thing my backend is running on port 5000 and frontend on port 3000

**Please tell how to set the cors options to see cookies in browser as well**

### authMiddleware

```
const protect = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    token = req.cookies.jwt;

    if (token) {
        try {
            const decode = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            req.user = await User.findById(decode.id).select("-password");

            next();
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error("Not authorized token failed");
        }
    }
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("You are not logged in!");
    }
});
```

### generate Token

```
export const generateToken = (res, id, expiryTime) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: expiryTime || "1d",
    });

    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development", // Use secure cookies in production
        sameSite: "strict", // Prevent CSRF attacks
        maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
    });
};
```

### index.js middlewares where cookie is declared

```
// CORS
    app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true, // Enable sending cookies
}));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
```

these are things i used to verify user if any other thing you want to know feel free to comment